# CSS3 transparent mask

Tags: html, css, transparent, mask

Below is CSS3 code for a loading wheel. The .wheel:after property takes a chunk out of the circle. The problem is that it is coloured to the background color to make it look like a chink is missing. The background colour may change so I want this to be transparent but still take the chink out of the circle. How?

```
.wheel {
    position:absolute;   
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0FACE7;
    -webkit-animation: spn 1s infinite linear;
    animation: spn 1s infinite linear;
}
.wheel:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #222;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: This sort of question would do better with a working snippet ;)

Comment: That would make things much more simple @jbutler483 +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Replace one of the borders (eg. border-right) with a transparent colour

This will give a three quarter wheel. To get less than this use the :after property to create another three quarter wheel and then CSS3 transform to rotate it to the desired angle.

```
.wheel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    margin: -10.5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0FACE7;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation: spn 1s infinite linear;
}

.wheel:after {
    margin: -1px;
    display: block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0FACE7;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve what you want I believe with just CSS pseudo elements using rgba and border properties.

You can use the :before as an overlay and the :after as the actual spinner.

I've put together this JS Bin to show how you could do this using borders.

http://jsbin.com/kuqagarece/2/

I did this for [whirl](http://jh3y.github.io/whirl).

Using a CSS class that you apply to a container you can add a loading spinner to any block element that can be simply switched on and off by applying a classname.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could use RGBA

```
.wheel:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  //red, green, blue, alpha
}
```

This provides transparency, as the alpha channel deals with opacity. If you'd like a script alternative, you could use jQuery to manipulate the background colour.

```
$('#element').css('background-color','transparent');
```

Obviously you'd need to add a function to that, based on whether you click this "wheel" or how it interacts with the user, but by using jQuery you could animate the transition between having a slice of this wheel removed and its previous state.

Comment: That would simply show the border of the circle underneath

Comment: @RobinKnight remove the border then. Lol

Comment: The I wouldn't have a spinning wheel surely?

Comment: What I answered was a simplified version of jh3y. My answer outlined what you could do to solve your problem, unlike jh3y, I didn't write the obvious code for you.